# Can't install gd library on RedHat5 and php 5.3.6

Tags: redhat, php5, php5-gd

I followed some tutorial on the web but I can't figure out how to install them.
I have RH5 and php 5.3.6. 
I typed `yum install php-gd` and it get me

> Parsing package install arguments
>   No Match for argument: php-gd
>   Nothing to do

Tryed with `php5-gd` and still nothing to do.
How to install them?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a compiled install of php. You just need to install GD and recompile php with support for gd

Comment: Yes I have installed php from   webtatic.repo .
How to install it and recompile php?

Answer (score 0):

`yum install php5-gd` really should install the needed module. If it doesn't do it, the module is probably already installed. If you create a simple web page containing line

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

and load that page in your web browser, does it list GD extension?

Comment: no, as I told you before it didn't install php5-gd either. And no, with phpinfo I don't see any gd module enabled